# Get Jekyll Posts by Year

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

I'm making an "archive" if you will of all the posts on my site.  I want to gather all the posts from a year.  This code works fine, however; I want it to generate the `<h2>2014</h2>` when needed.

**Basically, if year is 2014, render** `<h2>2014</h2>` **and make a** `<ul>` **of all the posts (with category of journal) from that given year.**

If anyone knows of any `.rb` plugins that archive by year, let me know!

```
<h2>2014</h2>
{% for post in site.categories.journal %}
    {% capture year %}{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}{% endcapture %}
        {% if year == "2014" %}
                <ul class="posts-in-year">
                    <li><p><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a> &mdash; {{ post.date | date: "%B %d" }}</p></li>
                </ul>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
{% for post in site.categories.journal %}
    {% capture year %}{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}{% endcapture %}
        {% if year == "2014" %}
                <h2>{% year %}</h2>
                <ul class="posts-in-year">
                    <li><p><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a> &mdash; {{ post.date | date: "%B %d" }}</p></li>
                </ul>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'year' in journal/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a year field in your posts and then

```
<h2>2014</h2>
<ul class="posts-in-year">
  {% for post in (site.categories.journal | where: "year","2014" | sort: 'date') %}
    <li><p><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
      {{ post.title }}</a> &mdash; {{ post.date | date: "%B %d" }}</p>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>2014</h2>
    <ul class="posts-in-year">
    {% for post in site.categories.journal %}
     {% capture year %}{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}{% endcapture %}
        {% if year == "2014" %}
            <li><p><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a> &mdash; {{ post.date | date: "%B %d" }}</p></li>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```