# Archive Jekyll Posts by Year

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

I'm making an "archive" if you will of all the posts on my site.  I want to gather all the posts from a year.  This code works fine, however; I want it to generate the `<h2>2014</h2>` when needed.

**Basically, if year is 2014, render** `<h2>2014</h2>` **and make a** `<ul>` **of all the posts (with category of journal) from that given year.**

If anyone knows of any `.rb` plugins that archive by year, let me know!

```
<h2>2014</h2>
{% for post in site.categories.journal %}
    {% capture year %}{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}{% endcapture %}
        {% if year == "2014" %}
                <ul class="posts-in-year">
                    <li><p><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a> &mdash; {{ post.date | date: "%B %d" }}</p></li>
                </ul>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Update: I just noticed that [Get Jekyll Posts by Year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179283/get-jekyll-posts-by-year) is a duplicate as well. Unfortunately I can't change my flag, otherwise I would point to this question: [Jekyll/Liquid Templating: How to group blog posts by year?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19086284/6884)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for post in site.categories.journal %}
  {% capture currentyear %}{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}{% endcapture %}
  {% if currentyear != year %}
     <h2>{{ currentyear }}</h2>
    {% capture year %}{{currentyear}}{% endcapture %} 
  {% endif %}
  <ul class="posts-in-year">
    <li><p><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}    </a> &mdash; {{ post.date | date: "%B %d" }}</p></li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```